# Apex Test Class for Contact via Phone number trigger

Tags: unit-test

I am relatively new to writing APEX code (Yes, I know this is how most of these questions start)...

I have managed to write the trigger I want to run, however I am having some real difficulty in writing the associated Test Method for the trigger.

The code I have is below:

```java
trigger MatchwithContactPhone on Conference_Calls__c (before insert, before update) {
    Map<String,Conference_Calls__c[]> assotiactedContactbyPhone = new Map<String,Conference_Calls__c[]>();

    for(Conference_Calls__c assCon : trigger.New) {
        if(!assotiactedContactbyPhone.containsKey(assCon.Called_Number__c)){
            assotiactedContactbyPhone.put(assCon.Called_Number__c, new Conference_Calls__c[]{});
        }

        assotiactedContactbyPhone.get(assCon.Called_Number__c).add(assCon);
    }

    for(Contact c : [select Id, Phone, Email, Name from contact where Phone in : assotiactedContactbyPhone.keySet()]){
        for(Conference_Calls__c assCon : assotiactedContactbyPhone.get(c.Phone)){
            assCon.Contact__c = c.Id;
        }
    }
}
```

If someone could let me know a Test Method that may be used with this Trigger I would be super grateful.

Comment: @Chance That is 100% incorrect. Not only can you test a trigger, you *must*.  For Dan, there is a quality [Trailhead module](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/apex_testing/units/apex_testing_triggers) on how to design and implement tests for triggers.

Comment: @Chance Triggers can be tested just fine, much like any other code. Current best practice is to keep triggers "logic-less" (preferring discrete classes instead), but that's something OP can worry about later.

Comment: @davidReed Hmmm. I don't know where I got that information. Thank you for correcting me.

Comment: Hi Dan, welcome to SFSE. Please take a moment to scroll through the [tour] and read [ask]. Asking "How do I do X?" without showing an attempt is generally going to be closed, as it doesn't really conform to the guidelines in the [help]. We expect a good faith effort here to attempt to solve the problem, or at least research it. As David mentions, take a look at some **Trailhead** modules to develop your basic skill set, then bring *specific* questions here.

Comment: This test class is 7 lines of code, so I wrote a little something, but @Adrian is right, usually these questions are closed. Next time, bring some of your own code, and we'll be happy to help!

Comment: Also note that generally if a question gets closed and you edit it to be more on topic, it must be reopened. But when there is an answer already, avoid changing your question so radically that post no longer makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever I write a test class (and I've been writing a lot of them lately), I focus on the starting point, and the end result.

To start with, what data do you need in order to test this trigger? A number of `Conference_Calls__c` records, with a `Called_Number__c` field equal to a contact in the databases `Phone`? So lets start there.

```
String somePhone = '(758) 771-0091';

Conference_Calls__c conferenceCall = new Conference_Calls__c(Called_Number__c = SomePhone);
Contact someContact = new Contact(Phone = somePhone);

insert someContact;
insert conferenceCall;
```

Now that you've got your data in place, you need to trigger your code. In this case, we already have, the `insert` caused your trigger to run, and there should be some baseline coverage. For other code, you might have to call it, or set up a more complicated starting point for your data, but this is an easy example. Now, we need to `assert` that the test ran as expected.

The first step here is to query the data again. Even though you already have it in memory, that data is out of sync from the data in the database.

```
conferenceCall = [SELECT Id, Contact__c FROM Conference_Calls__c WHERE Id = :conferenceCall.Id];
```

Then, assert that your conference call has the proper id set in this field. This is checking to make sure that our ending data is correctly placed, and that the trigger ran as expected. If there were any problems, or the values didn't line up, this is where the test would fail.

```
System.assertEquals(someContact.Id, conferenceCall.Contact__c);
```

Knowing how the data starts, how the data should look at the end, and causing the steps in the middle to happen are the three big steps to making a test class. A good understanding of your code and the steps involved help a lot too!

I've pretty much written a basic test class here, but theres still more to check, and this is where test classes can be either worthless, or worth their weight in gold. Covering known bugs to make sure they don't happen again, covering weird corner cases, or checking for installed dependencies, and covering 100% of a class are where test classes can really pull their weight.

For this class, taking it up a notch would be to `update` your conference call, after creating an extra contact, and changing your conference calls number that contacts. Then, `assert` that the contact changed as expected, to ensure that both `insert` and `update` operations are covered.

Comment: Thank you so much for your complete and insightful answer. It has helped tremendously and I appreciate the fact you shouldn't really be responding, so thanks again! @adrianlarson thank you for clarifying the rules I will ensure that I don't ask anything without at least attempting it first.